# Setting text in an input field of an executable program running on windows

Tags: java, .net, windows-services, awtrobot

I am working on an existing library management software (offline) of a college which is made in vb.net. I am thinking *to add the Biometric identification system* like fingerprint, which I would map in database and authenticate user/member.

The problem is we have just the executable of the current software from the management, but no source code. So in order to implement the biometrics, I need to decompile or disassemble the exe.

I was just wondering, if there is a way to feed that biometric input into the software without making any change to it, like setting the textbox or inputbox to some value automatically by using any windows service or using `Robot` class of Java, is it possible with these options, or I have NO choices left?

Comment: Please don't `highlight random` text as code.

Comment: I don't think you understand the purpose of code formatting.

Comment: sorry for improper formatting, its now been corrected.

Comment: Yes, this is possible, but no, Java is not the best tool for the job since you are best served using a language that gets close to the OS. Having said that, I've created something similar with Java's Swing and Robot, with JNA, but I did not find it easy or completely satisfactory.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels : thanx, for giving hope. will you please tell me more about the way to do it.

Comment: @RoshanJha: For my money, I'd first look into using a Window's automation scripting utility such as AutoIt V3 or something similar. You'll likely be up and running much more quickly by going this route.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels : ok.. thanx for the guidance, sir.